# Does the universe have a physical boundary based on the Islamic contents?

Tags: science, universe

Are there any Quranic verses or hadiths which talk about the end of the world? I mean "Are we limited by the universe physical boundaries" and if some day human is able to travel to the furthest point, is there any physical limit? if yes, how is it?

Answer (score 2):

First of all the universe has no ends, and there is nothing called the end of the universe
see this [link](http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/question.php?number=166).

But there is something in the Quran about this:

> O company of jinn and mankind, if you are able to pass beyond the regions of the heavens and the earth, then pass. You will not pass except by authority [from Allah].[[55:33]](http://quran.com/55/33)

Answer (score 1):

Indirectly, yes; given that the universe was created by Allah, a number of things follow from this by reflection.

The current scientific consensus is that the universe is very, very large, and still expanding; but it is still finite in size; it is not *infinite*.

This is consistent with the universe beginning in a 'Big Bang' several billion years ago; essentially an explosion of light; compare with *Genesis* in the *Injil* 'Let there be light'.

There are many physical limits: when I jump, I always fall back down the ground; this is gravity; an expression of Allahs Laws for the universe.

Only man has been given free will; and the knowledge of what is good and evil; it is his choice to accept the laws of Allah: Islam as submission; for everything else, the inanimate in particular: stars, planets and galaxies they follow Natural Law, which is only Allahs Will made manifest in the world; they submit without exception.

Much of this simply follows, or is consistent with the fact that nothing in this world is infinite; everything in this world in finite - only Allah is infinite; and He is veiled from us; whilst we are in this world.

Answer (score -1):

Since the beginning, with the big bang our universe comprises of three basic components, up til yet.

1. Heaven
2. Earth
3. Sound

Any bang has a sound and when we speak of big bang theory...there must be big sound waves that goes with it...which are yet to reach us to actually cause qayamat i suppose... Escaping heaven would be like escaping judgement day...

Comment: Good answer, it deserved an up vote if it was supported by references from Quran and scientific contents.